# How to download XSD schema with all imports in linux

Tags: xml, xsd

Is there a way to automatically download a XSD file with all imports from a linux console, knowing a URL of main XSD?

Comment: If I understand well, you don't want to do any xml-xsd validation, you only want to download the XSD at one URL and the XSDs that the XSD imports, is that right?

Comment: Yes. In the matter of fact, I'm creating AWS Lambda function to parse a RIF-CS document. I have come across xml4js library and it suppose to downlad XSD automatically, except it does not in case of RIF-CS and throws an error. I have tried to manually download each XSD and attach it using xml4js function, but even after that it still unable to parse the document and throws an error. I have post the code, xsd's and sample of xml into my experimental github: https://github.com/wizman777/Experements/blob/master/Node.js/xml4js/test.js At this moment I have run out of options and using xml2js.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not familiar with most of the technolgies you are talkin about, I am only familiar with w3c XML Schema, usually called XSD. The XSD whose imports you want to download is an w3c XML Schema?

Comment: No, it's a registry object xml schema. But I had working with it before from a Java application (using JAXB) with no problem so it has to be well formatted. My guess is what xml4js module does not works correctly with some of xsd tags. Be it as it may, it is not so important now, I have switched to xml2js and it does not require xsd to be loaded at all.

Answer (score 2):

A Node.js package called [cxsd](https://github.com/charto/cxsd) can do this. You can install it and download schema files like this (run the commands in a new directory):

```
echo '{ "scripts": { "cxsd": "cxsd" } }' > package.json
npm install cxsd
npm run cxsd http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd
```

It also works on Windows if you omit the single quotes (`'`).

All the required `.xsd` files from different hosts will appear under a new directory `cache/xsd/<hostname>/<path...>/<name>.xsd`.

As a bonus, it will compile the defined namespaces to TypeScript `.d.ts` files and tables for the [cxml](https://github.com/charto/cxml) parser, and save them inside a new directory `xmlns`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of how to do it in Groovy/Gradle.  It downloads all the files to a **xsd** directory.  I'm using the Bluetooth XSD as an example, you'll have to adjust your code accordingly.

```
def downloadXsd(url, dest) {
    println "Downloading ${url}"

    // strip off the protocol
    def uri = new URI(url)
    def path = "${uri.host}/${uri.path}"
    def destfile = new File("${dest}/${path}".replace("//", "/"))

    destfile.getParentFile().mkdirs()

    def file = destfile.newOutputStream()
    file << new URL(url).openStream()
    file.close()

    def xsd = new XmlSlurper()
        .parse(destfile)
        .declareNamespace('xs':'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')

    assert xsd instanceof groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult

    xsd.'xs:include'.each {
       downloadXsd("http://schemas.bluetooth.org/Documents/${it.@schemaLocation}", dest)
    }
}
```

And here is a gradle task that invokes it

```
task downloadXSD << {
    downloadXsd('http://schemas.bluetooth.org/Documents/characteristic.xsd', 'xsd')
}
```